# Why is the community biased against long questions?

Tags: discussion, voting

Why are some people so eager to downvote or close questions that are relatively long?

If they are engaged in a very complicated project and need to paste all that code (it's hard to make it a smaller example), why is it closed as not concise (not a minimal example)? Why don't people actually take time to go through it? If they don't want to go through it than why don't they leave and just leave the question and not say anything. If you *can't solve the long problem*, why be aggressive and *close the problem*. Doesn't make much sense. I just saw one like this:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517631/knights-tour-in-python*

or this:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502632/uva-online-judge-10484*

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: Questions that are long aren't necessarily bad, but there's certainly a correlation between really long questions and questions that are too broad, unclear, not providing a *minimal* reproducible example, etc.  Of course, not all long questions are downvoted/closed either.

Comment: Since we don't know the thought of other people, it's hard to say, but there's a good chance that this actually is closed for good reasons. Do you have a specific example of this?

Comment: The first question you linked started out as just an unformatted code dump, without actually asking a question. I'm surprised it doesn't have more downvotes.

Comment: For the second question `"I can't find where the error is" + wall of text = no one wants to answer`

Comment: "Why is the community super biased against wall of text questions" Because they are hard to read.

Comment: @TylerH: but *that* is not necessarily so. Only if written bad.

Comment: @Jongware No, text with no visual breaks is hard to read even if the author is Doctor Seuss. Humans need thematic separation in the form of discrete paragraphs, or words will run together and our brains will lose the ability to store groups of individual words together as phrases in our short-term memory, and we will be forced to go back and read, painfully, again and again. In short, sensory overload.

Comment: @TylerH: ah, that sort of wall of text – the badly written ones. Just yesterday I tried to format such a beast and the author *kept on editing it*, with trivial additions no less. He won and I gave up. I didn't even check back for down/close votes either.

Comment: See [Should Stack Overflow be awarding “A”s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/191410)

Comment: Your second example is "Here's a code dump ***plaumph*** debug it for me".  Screw that guy.

Comment: voting on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) appears to go against assumption made here. Is it not long enough to trigger that bias?

Comment: My [only question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300673/label-printer-starts-printing-blank-pages-in-large-jobs) is a pretty long question.  You know what differentiates it from most of the wall of text questions?  **Effort**.

Comment: "it's hard to make it a smaller example" Hard is not impossible. A bit of effort can be expected. "Why don't people actually take time to go through it?" They are lazy (as everyone in the world) and prefer to spent the lowest amount of time possible. "why don't they leave and just leave the question and not say anything." People here are biased and likely to downvote. On the other hand it may be justified. The long question you post as example may just be a bad question. Probably long questions are more often bad questions than short questions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a balance between providing enough information to describe your problem, and providing too much information such that it's impossible to see where the problem is. That's why one of the common close reasons contains a link to how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The two questions you point out had different flaws in them that caused them to be downvoted. The first question looked like this in [its original incarnation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31517631/1):

> **Knight's Tour in python**
>
> matrix=[] r=9 for i in range(r):
>       innerrow=[]
>       for j in range(r):
>           innerrow.append(-1)
>       matrix.append(innerrow)
>
> def reset():
>       for i in range(r):
>           innerrow=[]
>           for j in range(r):
>               innerrow.append(-1)
>           matrix.append(innerrow)
>        mov=[[2,1],[2,-1],[-2,1],[-2,-1],[1,2],[1,-2],[-1,2],[-1,-2]] count=0
>
> def poss(x,y):
>       if 0<= x < r and 0 <= y < r and matrix[x][y] == -1:
>           return True
>       return False
>        def displace(x,y,cnt):
>       if cnt == r*r:
>           return True
>       for i in range(len(mov)):
>           m = x +mov[i][0]
>           n = y + mov[i](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
>           if poss(m, n):
>               matrix[m][n]=cnt
>               if displace(m, n,cnt+1):
>                   return True
>               else:
>                   matrix[m][n] = -1
>       return False
>
> matrix[0][0]=0 if displace(0,0,1)==True:
>       print matrix
>       print "\n"

There was no problem statement, no text, and no question at all. There was no way anyone could answer that. It was downvoted and closed. Then, the asker edited it into an actual question and the community reopened it. I'd say that process worked well.

The second question is also hard to understand. A title of "UVa online judge 10484" makes no sense to most people, and only because I've seen quite a few students post these do I recognize that it's referring to the University of Virginia's computer science program and an online code verifier. Unless you're a student at UVa, that's not a helpful description.

Beyond that, they just say this:

> I complied the code and it works fine on my side, but when i upload
>   the code, it returns runtime error on the online judge.
>
> I can't find where the error is, so I would be grateful for any help.

No other information is provided, so we don't know what kind of "runtime error" they saw, where it occurred, or any other information about this problem. They're now asking volunteers to look through every line of their code to see if they can spot an error. Most of us don't feel that's an effective use of our time.

Yes, we do want people to provide as much detail as they can, but we do want the information in questions to be narrowed down to the core of the problem. It's not just how much information is presented in a question, but that it's the right kind of information.

Comment: University of Virginia student can't capitalize their i's.   Mmmm.....

Comment: What you say is that the questions were of low quality. One problem is that some less experienced people may find it hard to present the right kind of information, especially if they don't know exactly what is wrong. Looks like the OP needs a course in how to ask good questions.

Comment: @Trilarion: don't start using *"low quality"* as a catchall term, or synonymous with "lack of effort". In this case *"state the question clearly in generic language, avoid acronyms, jargon or obscure references a general audience won't understand"*

Answer (score 12):

I don't think the community is biased against long questions. When properly composed, a very in-depth set of code, descriptions, explanations, and error results most often results in a very well received question.

The problem that the community takes issue with, from my observation, are just simply massive copy paste sections of code without any real effort to manipulate them into actual examples.

The problem here is that now the community as a whole must take the time to manipulate this code into something that can be tested and reproduced. What makes this worse is that if multiple users are attempting to help solve this problem, *each user must take time to craft the code into a reproducible issue*. As a result, say this takes 10 minutes and there were 6 users, a whole hours worth of time was wasted, when the OP could have simply composed the situation into something which was reproducible.

Furthermore, with a reproducible situation more users would be able to address the solution because they would no longer be wasting their time doing something mundane.

In conclusion, yes, it makes a lot of sense that questions which disregard others' time in the form of expecting their example to be composed into a reproducible problem should be closed. Collectively they waste hours upon hours of time from users who are already strapped for time trying to help others.

*Help us help you.*

Comment: @ryanyuyu - I am not sure I understand your comment? I think that post is a prime example of what I am talking about though. In order to highlight the error a user (or group of users) would all at the same time be taking the code into an IDE and then narrowing it down in order to make it small enough to contain the scope of the error, and then identify the aspect of it which was reproducible, and then after all of that (which should have been done by the OP) they can provide a solution to address the nuanced aspect identified which was causing the error.

Comment: Oh sorry.  I meant to leave it on the question.  My bad, but please feel free to use it as an example.

Comment: "I don't think the community is biased against long questions." I like this answer a lot as it is very constructive, but the first sentence is not really backed by any statistics and should be regarded more as an opinion. We don't know really if there is a bias against long questions. Probably it is very difficult to find out if there would be one.

Answer (score -8):

I actually like this question and I have noticed this as well. I will admit some people do put a lot of redundant information and lazily shove EVERYTHING in as an example. That is not cool and shows little effort to allow other users to understand the problem. But there are cases where the user does follow the guidelines and gets penalized for it (and this is my problem with some of the privileges being earned by points). One example is a question I posted recently here: [How to display multiple items on one graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551116/how-to-display-multiple-items-on-one-graph)

I got a -1 for it and I kept it within the guidelines. The coding I gave was severely cut short to what was necessary and saved other users having to examine an extra 800+ lines of coding that was very similar. My details regarding the question was kept to the point and specific to the question and in the end I stated my question and what I was trying to achieve. But apparently that was an incorrect format. In fact quite often I noticed that many users fixate more on lecturing others on how to post a question than actually bothering to answer the question at all. I agree with you, if there is actually nothing significantly wrong about the question and the user is not going to help, they must just leave it.

Personally I feel the users on here need to be a bit more lenient, and more importantly should apply to have certain privileges and there should be some sort of moderation to protect some users from those that are biased or abuse their privileges. I also find that some high ranked users become increasingly rude towards the much lower ranked users.

So to answer your question I wouldn't claim it as users being biased but rather there are those that are to strict with the rules and that there are definitely unfair actions imposed on users. Most likely some users tend to get a big head when they achieve high ranks and unfortunately there are a lot of people that become like that. But if this is how you feel about what is happening on this site I think try and take it up with one of the proper admins/developers of Stackexchange and see what they have to say. I myself have sent a report to them regarding a similar issue.

Comment: Well, it's certainly a problem that nearly all your prose is one humungous big ball of words, without any structure. Learn to use paragraphs and line-breaks better. Aside from that, there's a close-vote for "no mcve", and at a first glance the code you posted certainly isn't one. As it's outside my area of interest and is difficult to parse, I won't take the time to understand your blob to decide whether that's justified. Anyway, if you want help fixing your question (or understanding what if anything needs fixing), post a question and not an answer to a (though only just) related question.

Comment: @Deduplicator You just proved my point

Comment: No, downvoting you here for your answer not being useful doesn't score you any points, however much you want to see it that way. Anyway, don't take it so hard, votes on meta have no effect on your reputation (at least the one measured in unicorn points) and priveges.

Comment: @Deduplicator And btw, there's nothing wrong with my paragraph structure, if you are intimidated by too many words that's your problem. And as expected my answer got minus one because you "admins" find the truth a bit hard to swallow. I noticed any questions and answers that point out negative but FACTUAL information about this site get minus points

Comment: i upvoted yr question

Comment: I fixed your SO question...