# Is it better to err on the long side or the short side when writing questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

Today [I wrote a long question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546137/uitableview-with-variable-cell-height-working-in-ib-but-not-programmatically). I think I included all the details needed that an experienced programmer in those tags would need to solve it. I know that [long questions are OK on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252230/when-is-it-appropriate-to-ask-a-long-question) when the situation requires and that there [isn't a bias](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299715/why-is-the-community-biased-against-long-questions) per se against long questions. However, I am afraid that the length of some of my questions may scare away people who could answer them. I know I've blown off other people's questions (and answers) that look too long.

I could have made my question shorter by leaving out some of the explanation or supplemental code and then providing it if asked. Some of the length, though, I feel is required by the Stack Overflow community to prove that I did my research and tried everything I could on my own first.

I know [it's a balance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299723/3681880), but when I am unsure how much information to include, should I err on the long side or the short?

Comment: Just ask yourself: does my question represent a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifyable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this with anything but _"The question has to be as long as it needs to be."_

Comment: Stealing Blaise Pascal's quote: "I'm sorry that this was such a long question, but I didn't spend enough time on it to make it a short one".

Comment: The question does seem *really* long. I'm not familiar with the tech you're using, so i can't really comment on what is needed or isn't, but generally i don't care that you're "trying to make a suggestion bar for a custom Mongolian keyboard," instead what i'm interested in reading is "The cell heights are not resizing and the custom vertical labels are overlapping each other.", in other words, **the real problem** in simple terms. That line is 4 page downs from the top of the page.

Comment: @KevinB but "trying to make a suggestion bar for a custom Mongolian keyboard," should still be mentioned to avoid an X/Y problem

Comment: Long enough to be Complete. Short enough to be Minimal.

Comment: Questions should be made [as simple as possible, but no simpler](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple). IMHO, it would be nice if Stack Exchange site supported collapsible "spoiler" sections that could be used for supplementary information.

Comment: *Some of the length, though, I feel is required by the Stack Overflow community to prove that I did my research and tried everything I could on my own first.* - that is evident from focusing the question on a narrow, isolated problem. Excessive length makes it look like the opposite: like you're throwing tonnes of irrelevant information in there because you have no idea where the problem is or because the question is excessively broad in scope.

Comment: The conversational style of the posting makes it look like a dev blog and not a question.

Answer (score 12):

**We need more complex questions**

I like your question, even though it is lengthy. I wish there more interesting questions that show where their research went, and what some surrounding details were. There is some meat left on the bone there as far as problem solving goes.

**We also need more positive feedback**

From a "every user" perspective, I strongly disagree with this type of question being problematic. While it may go unanswered - or at least unsolved - that is more a result of it being too specific a topic as opposed to a flawed question. We need more content like this, and it should be encouraged. There is a lot of guidance out there for what to do with bad questions, but not enough towards good ones. It is quite simple, an upvote will suffice. That it is not possible to answer for you (or me at the moment since it is not in my specialty) does not mean it should be discouraged.

**It could have been more compact**

This could have gone in a different direction. As with all problems it is best to narrow in on them by reproducing them from smaller and smaller scenarios until it is very clear which exact metric is creating the problem (where possible). I feel like your question takes some steps towards this, but in the end the code shown was still specific to your implementation and not towards a more generic project which is what more problem solvers will try to plug the code into.

**Support questions which show effort and research**

With the move from MSO to MSE one thing that was lost was the balance between closing bad questions and sending positive signal to good questions. There is a lot of content on what to close, how to close it, what to downvote, why downvoting is necessary, etc. etc. - it is all valid. However, there needs to be a balance. If a question is a good question, it needs an upvote to encourage good content and to help others discern the mediocre from the research. If as a user you post an answer, then why leave the question without an upvote? Upvoting well researched questions encourages research.

Comment: Your third point is especially helpful for me. Reproducing the problem from smaller and smaller scenarios. I could try and reproduce the problem with a simplified custom class or even a standard view. Doing that would cut the length of the question down as well as make it easier for others to replicate.

Comment: _"We need more complex questions"_ - no, we need more questions about complex problems, which is something entirely different. This is a complex question, possibly made complicated by the OP, about a UI thingy. Not that I'm saying that UI questions can't be interesting, but it comes down to: "you can't do that", "you can do it with a workaround", "you're doing it wrong", or "there's a bug in the UI framework".

Comment: A rather pedantic take on "complex questions". Do you think I had truly intended this to mean that we need more obfuscation in questions? I hope not. Your comment really reads more like a troll remark than an actual response.

Comment: Well thanks for that feedback... I wast just meaning to clarify any confusion that could arise from the description in your first paragraph, but thanks for responding so seriously.

Answer (score 11):

I'm trying to create an element programatically, but I'm receiving an error:

> error: x

Whilst using the following code:

```
int main(){
    return y;
}
```

The error appears on line **z**

I've set the top and bottom pin contstraints so not sure what else could be causing this error.

---

This is what the format of your post *could/should* have looked like. There isn't really any need for a progress update, a list of questions that you've researched or how you tried to isolate the problem.

The fact that you isolated the problem to specific subset of your code is enough, just give us that code (in context) and explain what the issue is. If you have a "tl:dr" heading then that should be a big red flag telling you that you've got too much waffle going on in your question.

---

> This error has been brought up before multiple times on Stack Overflow:

We don't need to know this, we can check ourselves if we suspect your question is a duplicate and vote accordingly.

---

> The problem probably lies in / I think the problem is probably in here

Again, not really needed - either someone knows the answer to your question, in which case they will not need these suggestions, or they don't; in which case the suggestions still don't help.

---

It may seem like I'm being overly-critical here but there is a valid reason and although many people don't agree with it, I'll bet most people do the same.

#### If I haven't understood the context of your problem in the first few lines, I'll just go to another question.

There, I said it, it's out there.

This is one of the reasons for giving a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example - at the end of the day most of us are volunteers that answer questions in our free time for no tangible reward, so we're going to be picky about which questions we spend our time answering; make your question appealing by getting straight to the point.

Comment: If you cannot read past the first few lines of a question, then you are not giving complex questions a chance. This is part of the problem with question asking in general, users are not providing positive feedback to questions which took effort to ask. Just because it takes a few minutes to grok a complex question doesn't mean it should be closed. Fine, move on if you don't like it, but there isn't really much grounds for closure. I would rather see more questions with more than enough as opposed to questions asking why they keep getting null reference (or some other mundanely easy question).

Comment: I agree that complex/long isn't a reason for closure, but there is a side effect of a question being too complex/long in that many people, myself and probably macro man included, will simply skip past it. If you don't see that as a problem, great, keep on keeping on. I would prefer a question I asked to be short enough to not lose the interest of the people looking for questions to answer.

Comment: I would probably have to try pretty hard to get question banned at this point. but... I'm not sure why that is relevant.

Comment: I like the concise question format that you provided. I think I could work more on moving that type of information to the front of my question. I also think that including links to similar questions is a waste. I don't think I can leave that out, though, duplicate markers are not careful enough to analyze whether the other questions really are duplicates or not. You can also see that I got three answers that were just repeats of things in those other questions. Another reason for some of this narrative content is that I used to get downvoted before when I didn't include that type of thing.

Comment: Overall, I take your point, though, that short and direct in the first few lines is best.

Comment: I really like how you put forth on the question format to capture attention, great stuff, thanks.

Comment: @TravisJ completely agree with your premise, and something I've touched on before in meta. The system is designed in a way that we intrinsically look for reasons to close/downvote first. The point of my answer however isn't about downvoting or closing as the question isn't a bad one _per se_ - I'm just trying to give pointers as to why people may overlook the question in favour of one that can be answered quicker. I'm not saying that's right, but it is generally what happens.

Comment: I don't agree with removing *"This error has been brought up before multiple times on Stack Overflow:"*. Without this many people will blindly close vote as a duplicate

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Then that is an issue with the community, not the question, which should be addressed separately.

Comment: @Alexander simply stating "this is not a duplicate" proves nothing and must be removed.

Comment: @CodeCaster I've seen loads of questions that were closed as duplicate (either by separate votes or magic gold dupe hammer) that weren't actually duplicates. Including at least one similar question and explaining the difference avoids having half your comment section about whether it's a dupe or not and makes people focus on answering instead. But I do agree it's a community problem macroman, it's just a necessary evil sometimes.

Comment: @Alexander yeah but then still, voting without reading is a community problem. It's true that it's a prerequisite to show your research in your question, and naming at least one similar question and explaining why it isn't a duplicate helps. I was arguing against merely the phrase "this is not a duplicate" without proof, which is also very common. I thought you were arguing for the latter case.

Comment: I've also seen many that were closed as a duplicate even with the statement "this is not a duplicate". Usually that statement provokes me to go and confirm that it isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

### Both.

Short introductory sentence, then a long question.

---

At the far end of the spectrum, the short end is the problem-solvers equivelant of clickbait; enough information to understand it and get interested. Programmers like me are drawn in by interesting problems, possibly even being [nerd sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/).

Ideally, I should be able to get a rough idea of your problem in the first few sentences. Any details that may be relevant should be pushed to the bottom. This applies to code too, if you have a short snippet that shows your problem well than put that at the top. I disagree with [Macro Man](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4240221/macro-man), you should show your research, including links to similar questions you've looked at and why they didn't help. I see no reason to omit guesses as to where the problem exists, as this is more information that potential answerers can use.

Answer (score 3):

In doubt, you should err on the short side.

There's always the possibility to request more information with comments and to amend the question by editing it.

Answer (score -1):

If you can provide short and long version, just show them both.

The short version is useful for a brief look on the question, long - for better understanding.

Example: [How to start a globally installed module as an application from the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31478431/4928642)

Comment: But, contrary to the example, make sure your title is spelled correctly.

Comment: @BenVoigt, ooops, fixed :)

Comment: I agree. I don't usually follow pop culture trends (tropes? memes?) but I have accepted the **TL:DR;** abbreviation and used it myself to provide a quick summary of a longer post. Of course, there is also something to be said for [Veni, vidi, vici](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici).

Answer (score -3):

Yes. But make sure it is at least 30 characters.

Comment: I was worth it, even for the downvote.