# How to deal with good, but long, questions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, this happens:

- There is a good question, clearly showing research effort,
  written clearly and showing a strong understanding of the problem.
- It is a long question (my definition is that it requires
  scrolling to get to the top of the first answer).
- The detail (however good) bloats the question, making the answers harder to scroll to (I know, I know, I'm lazy, but this ease of finding good answers is what makes Stack Overflow so great in my opinion).

For example, my process when searching for a programming solution is usually to:

1. Google the problem.
2. Find the most relevant SO link by title.
3. Look at the answers from highest voted downwards, completely ignoring the question text unless it (rarely) provides necessary context.

I would just edit the question, but I am reluctant to make drastic changes, especially if the only problem I have with it is that it is too long.

**So, how can I improve a question that seems longer than necessary? Or is this too minor of a problem to worry about?**

Notes:

- I'm assuming above that the extra detail is unnecessary (to most people).
- This question [Is it better to err on the long side or the short side when writing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320795/7470360) deals with a similar issue but from the perspective of the person who asked the question.
- If it would be helpful, I could provide an example, but I'm hesitant to add it, partly because I am biased (because I wrote an answer) and partly because I'd prefer a more general answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I improve a question that seems longer than necessary? Or is this too minor of a problem to worry about?

Most quality lengthy questions have an introductory paragraph that describe briefly the whole question. If such a paragraph is not present or does a bad job at summarizing the question, respectively add one or make it clearer.

> Is this too minor of a problem to worry about?

I think that yes, for the two following reasons:

A lengthy question is often related to a complex issue. Resolving a complex issue takes a lot of time. In the end, the time spent reading a question is very small compared to the time spent resolving a complex issue.

The main difficulty faced in resolving a complex issue is often more the lack of resources about the issue, so a few details that can seem superfluous for someone can sometimes save hours of debugging to another developer in a different setup.

Also it is very easy to observe that most questions on SO are incomplete and that is a huge complex issue. Your question (quite relevant still, upvoted) is the first post I encounter addressing the fact that questions might be too long. I'm pretty sure most SO users agree on `complete > not boring`.

Comment: This answer seems like the correct way to go. Considering that the opposite problem is much more common, it is much better to keep the detail, just in case it is useful, than to delete it and risk an unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer "long" over "short" questions as long as it contains all the information required to answer it fully. If trimming it down remove information required to answer the question fully, then it has the right length.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree, in the case where all the detail is necessary. But sometimes, there is a lot of detail which doesn't seem be needed, yet could be useful for someone. It is the second case I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

When a question contains a lot of information that's unnecessary then, if you think it's worth your time, edit the question to remove the noise.  You could also comment on the question to ask the author to try to edit the question to be more concise, which I'd do if you don't think the underlying question (once improved) is actually all that valuable, or if you don't have the writing skills to do a good job yourself.